# React JS - how do I loose focus on an element that was just clicked on?

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have a small react app that has some components  called `InfoBox`. each `InfoBox` is created with a `key` (for React), an `id` (for me), a `name`, `top_pos',`left_pos`, a`rings_visible`boolean, and a`focusOnRing`callback sent from the parent (the object that instantiates the`InfoBox`es) as props to the`InfoBox`

it is created in some parent code like this

```
 <InfoBox
              key={ele.key}
              id={ele.key}
              name={ele.name}
              top_pos={ele.top_pos}
              left_pos={ele.left_pos}
              focusOnRing={this._focusOnRing}
              rings_visible={(focused_ring === ele.key)}
            />
```

Here is the full `src/info_box.js` that I am working with...

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Rings from './rings'

const StyledBlurbBox = styled.div`
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: hidden;
`

const StyledInfoBox = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
`

const StyledH1 = styled.h1 `
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
`

export default class InfoBox extends React.Component {
  constructor({blurb}) {
    super()

    this.state = {
      name: (blurb ?  blurb.name : ""),
    }
  }


  render() {
    const top_pos = this.props.top_pos || 100
    const left_pos = this.props.left_pos || 400
    const {name, id, rings_visible, blurb} = this.props


    return (
      <div>
        <StyledInfoBox onClick={() => {this.props.focusOnRing(this.props.id) }}
         style={{top: top_pos + "%", left: left_pos + "%"}}>

          <Rings visible={rings_visible}
                 animation_sequence={['spinning', '']}/>

          <div className="vertical-center-container">
            <StyledH1>
              <button href="#" value={name}>{name}</button>
            </StyledH1>
          </div>
        </StyledInfoBox>


      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is best visually explained so I will explain it in screenshots.

my expected result is that when I click on an `InfoBox` (which happens to be `StyledInfoBox` below), some rings appear around it (they are another component called `Rings`)

However, when I make a click, the browser (Chrome) puts an annoying blue line around the text of what I have just clicked (the button maybe?) so it looks like this:

[image]

Expected result is this, no blue line, just the rings visible:

[image]

I *think* what I need to do is intercept the event (is that possible/recommended in React?) and blur (or de-focus) this button. but I'm not sure how to do this.

one interesting effect here that I am learning about React is that the when the virtual DOM re-renders (or mutates) the real DOM, elements keep their focus including if you are focused or blurred on an element in the DOM, as can be seen here.

Using React 16.9.0

UPDATE #1

my implementation of a solution proposed by @Nick using React `refs`. note the difference here is that I've attached the blur to the onClick method. in @Nick's answer below, it is attached to a setTimeout.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Rings from './rings'

const StyledBlurbBox = styled.div`
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: hidden;
`

const StyledInfoBox = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
`

const StyledH1 = styled.h1 `
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
`

export default class InfoBox extends React.Component {
  constructor({blurb}) {
    super()

    this.state = {
      name: (blurb ?  blurb.name : ""),
    }
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }


  render() {
    const top_pos = this.props.top_pos || 100
    const left_pos = this.props.left_pos || 400
    const {name, id, rings_visible, blurb} = this.props


    return (
      <div >
        <StyledInfoBox onClick={() => { this.buttonRef.current.blur(); this.props.focusOnRing(this.props.id) }}
         style={{top: top_pos + "%", left: left_pos + "%"}}>

          <Rings visible={rings_visible}
                 animation_sequence={['spinning', '']}/>

          <div className="vertical-center-container">
            <StyledH1>
              <button ref={this.buttonRef} href="#" value={name}>{name}</button>
            </StyledH1>
          </div>
        </StyledInfoBox>


      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: My instinct is that perhaps you're using the wrong type of component? Is `InfoBox` an input element and you don't want users to actually be able to input anything into it?

Comment: hmm…… it is just what you see above (file given in entirety). It does contain a `button` element inside of it, and it does look like the blue line is around precisely the `button` element itself, so that is interesting

Comment: Yeah, so the reason I replied with that question so quickly is because the blue focus ring added by chrome is pretty important for accessibility purposes, so (in my opinion) if you find yourself trying to get rid of it you should rethink whether you're using the right component in the first place

Comment: I guess I was previously encouraged to use `button` as preferred over a div or something less semantic. but it has the side-effect described above (with the focus being gained and the annoying blue line). I guess what I really want to know is about React itself, is there an 'event' that I can intercept, for example with a `.currentTarget` that I can then call `.blur()` on. please forgive my jQuery background.  does the question make sense?  the thing I'm not sure about is how to find/mutate the DOM element, which I'm not supposed to do in React?

Comment: in fact, if I just change the `button` to a `div` it works as expected. but I'm really looking for figuring out why I should or should not try to de-focus it as a button. (like, is that a bad practice?)

Comment: De-focusing isn't bad practice, but removing the outline, as suggested in the answers below, is a very bad practice. Out of curiosity, will it be used as an actual button?

Comment: well, yes… it is the thing clicked on (although unfairly I have attached the onClick handler higher up. but let's say I wanted to attach the onClick handler here)

Comment: if I wanted to de-focus it, how would I even access the DOM element? Can I tell React to de-focus it?

Comment: Yeah! You should do that using `ref`s

Answer (score 1):

You can access DOM elements in React using `ref`s. The following code shows a simple example that focuses on a button on initial load and then, after three seconds, unfocuses on that element.

I'd like to strongly suggest against the CSS solution of removing outlines from input elements and buttons. Outlines are accessibility features that shouldn't be tampered with unless you replace them with a suitable alternative.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myRef.current.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myRef.current.blur();
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button ref={this.myRef}>Thing</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Your solution is good, and it is what I *really* was in fact asking about React, however,   1) am not interested in the setTimeout-- the animation needs to be coupled to an onClick 2) even when I couple the animation to an onClick,  it does have another (different) defect-- which is best labeled "flash of focused button"

this symptom is that the blue line appears *momentarily* before disappearing and starting my won animation. However, it does go away when the native .blur() is called above inside of the onClick

Comment: you'll note that the blue line effect is caused by the user's click action itself, and is not present when the component is just rendered by itself. SO the setTimeout is not relevant because the user could click before or after the 3 seconds you specified and cause the blue line to re-appear.

Comment: basically think exectly what you have except the button has `onClick => {() => {this.myRef.current.blur() }`

Comment: Ah shoot, I didn't realize your rings are specifically focus rings. I'm going to delete my proposed answer because I actually think it'd be more appropriate to remove the default css outline than it is to unfocus the user...

Comment: well… arguments could be made both ways. in fact I really did want to learn about React so using the refs I think really gets at the *heart* of what I was asking, even if the CSS solution may be the most thorough way to do it (given the FOUF 'flash of unstyled focus' that is caused as a side-effect).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the focus outline then you can just use:

```
const StyledH1 = styled.h1 `
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  button:focus{
        outline: none;
  }
`
```

As mentioned in the comments this will cause accessibility issues as there becomes no visible indication for those navigating your page via keyboard

You could add different button focus theme/styling to reintroduce accessibility:

```
  button:focus{
        outline: thin dotted #E1CA80;
  }
```

Comment: but I'm kind of curious about the internal workings of React. But I accept that as a CSS solution this is a good one.

Comment: Please don't tell people to remove accessibility features: https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a react issue but a browser issue, if you do not specifically tell the browser to not show focus on an interactive element then it will show a focus. this is an accessibility issue especially those who only use keyboards

Comment: @Nick that is a good point but sometimes you don't the outline however I updated my answer with said caveat

Comment: @Willman.Codes -- it could very well be a browser issue but I am learning React so today, for me, it is a React issue!

Comment: I think you're right! Its a browser issue that can be solved a number of ways including with React (: cheers!

Comment: I will sleep on it but based on all of these answer I think perhaps both solutions are what I am looking for and I may combine them. I don't think that the position that setting the button's outline to none when focused is necessarily always bad, in my case, for example, I'm implementing my own indicator (which happens to be the fancy gold ring you see above)… so everything is relative.

Comment: There have been times when I prefer to not have any focus at all, but as Nick pointed out, do so with accessibility in mind. I also updated my answer to include how to indicate that it is focused but use your own theme/style to do so. (in this case its possible the best solution is not to use a button at all if its instead acting as a UI feature)